# change textcolor after textbox loses focus

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textbox, textcolor

I would like to change the textbox default textcolor to the original default color after item is added to a list.

XAML

```
<TextBox Name="AddLocationTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=AddLocationName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
         LostFocus="AddLocationTextBox_LostFocus" GotFocus="AddLocationTextBox_GotFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,37,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="285">                    

        <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding AddLocationCommand}" />
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Code behind in View

```
public LocationManagerView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AddLocationTextBox.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;   
}

private void AddLocationTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AddLocationTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    AddLocationTextBox.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
}

private void AddLocationTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)           
{
    AddLocationTextBox.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
}
```

ViewModel

```
public RelayCommand AddLocationCommand { get; private set; }
private void AddLocation()
{
    if ( AddLocationName != null)
    {
        Locations.Add(new Location()
        {
            Name = AddLocationName,
        });
        AddLocationName = "Enter New Location";
        Keyboard.ClearFocus();

        ////change textcolor to gray////
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }     
}
```

It's after AddLocationName is set again to "Enter New Location" I want to change the textcolor back to gray.
Looks like the Keyboard.ClearFocus() doesn't call the LostFocus method in the View.

Any Idea how I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the foreground of your `TextBox` to gray, instead of tying to force `AddLocationTextBox` to lose it's focus, you should change the foreground manually (i.e. use `AddLocationTextBox.Foreground = Brushes.Gray` instead of `Keyboard.ClearFocus()`).

If you're looking for a way to force currently focused element to lose focus, then you can use below code instead of `Keyboard.ClearFocus()` :

```
UIElement elementWithFocus = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
elementWithFocus.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```